# the number of ways in which $5$ men and $7$ women can stand in a queue such that exactly 6 women stand consecutively

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be the number of ways in which $5$ men and $7$ women can stand in a queue such that all the  women stand consecutively. Let $m$ be the number of ways in which the same 12 persons can stand in a queue such that exactly 6 women stand consecutively. Then the value of $\frac mn$ is
(A) 5
(B) 7
(C) $\frac 57$
(D) $\frac 75$

**Try**
Considering the $7$ women as a unit the $5$ men and the unit can be arranged in $6!$ ways. In each arrangement the $7$ women can arrange themselves in $7!$ ways. So total arrangements $n=7!\times 6!$.
But I'm stucked in the second part. Please help to understand the underlying counting technique. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second part, imagine arranging the men first by themselves in a line.  Now, pick a woman to stand by herself and which man or men to stand next to or between.  The remaining women as a group can then choose which man or men to stand next to or between and then arrange themselves within that space created.

Answer (score 0):

there are 5! ways of arranging the men

The group of 6 and the single woman can be positioned with respect to the men in
$$2 \binom 62=30$$ ways

the 7 women can be arranged in 7! ways

so $$m=30\times 5! \times 7! = 5n$$